# How can I marge similar text's section in MS Word document?

Tags: xml, merge, ms-word

When you read a XML `MS Word` document contained in a `.docx` file that has been renamed to `.zip`, you can see following lines

```xml
<w:p w14:paraId="67FBA348" w14:textId="004EFC1B" w:rsidR="001B6A5E" w:rsidRDefault="001B6A5E" w:rsidP="00F83240">
    <w:pPr>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:cs="Arial"/>
            <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
            <w:lang w:val="de-DE"/>
        </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:cs="Arial"/>
            <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
            <w:lang w:val="de-DE"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>Für die drei Fälle m=1, 2 und 3 gibt Formel (2) folgende Fun</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r w:rsidR="00DC2FF5">
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:cs="Arial"/>
            <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
            <w:lang w:val="de-DE"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>k</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:cs="Arial"/>
            <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
            <w:lang w:val="de-DE"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>tionen:</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
```

As you can see, some words has been splitted without understandable reasons !

To obtain complete sentence, I must now merge "similar" `<w:r>` element in only one `<w:r>` element as below.

```xml
<w:p w14:paraId="67FBA348" w14:textId="004EFC1B" w:rsidR="001B6A5E" w:rsidRDefault="001B6A5E" w:rsidP="00F83240">
    <w:pPr>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:cs="Arial"/>
            <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
            <w:lang w:val="de-DE"/>
        </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:cs="Arial"/>
            <w:szCs w:val="24"/>
            <w:lang w:val="de-DE"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>Für die drei Fälle m=1, 2 und 3 gibt Formel (2) folgende Funktionen:</w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
```

How can I merge or regroup splitted "similar" sentences from `MS Word` application ?

Is there a `MS Word` parameter that allow that ?

Comment: I don't think there are any settings in Word that you can use to control this behaviour. At least one reason for it *may have been* the way that Word uses "rsids" to indicate changes. There used to be a setting in Trust Center->Trust Center Settings...Privacy Options>"Store Random Numbers to improve accuracy" that would let you prevent Word from inserting these rsids. But that option seems to have gone and I don't think you could set it programmatically.

Comment: but, where can I find "Trust Center" menu or option ? For information, I use Microsoft Office 2016.

Comment: File->Options. In  German UI, probably Datei->Optionen->Sicherheitscenter->Einstellungen fuer das Sicherheitscenter->Datenschutzoptionen->Zufallzahlung fuer Verbesserung der Kombiniergenauigkeit speichern

Comment: Thanks. I tried to find your option but as you write, it seems to have gone ! 
I think that I will write a little program to do the job.